# How to select the first item in a list view by default?

Tags: qt, qlistview, qfilesystemmodel

I am using `QFileSystemModel` along with `QListView`, and I want the first item shown by the model to get selected by default.

How I do that every time I click an item ?

Answer (score 13):

Using `setCurrentIndex` should do the job:

```
view->setCurrentIndex(fsModel->index(0, 0));
```

`fsModel` here can be something like `view->model()`.

- [QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#setCurrentIndex)
- [QAbstractItemView::model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#model).

Comment: Just to those that don't find it obvious, fsModel here can be something like view->model()

Comment: Doing this in Python didn't do the job.
Apparently the main problem was that the underlying model IS NOT SORTED, while the QListView sorts the item by alphabet. Using index(0,0) resulted in a "random" item being selected.
The solution was to sort the model first: `fsModel.sort(0)`
After that index(0, 0) did actually select the first item in the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to select and click the first item:

```
ui->ListWidget->setCurrentRow(0);
QListWidgetItem* item = ui->ListWidget->item(0);
ui->ListWidget->itemClicked(item);
```

- [QListWidget::setCurrentRow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#setCurrentRow-1)
- [QListWidget::item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#item)
- [QListWidget::itemClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked)

Comment: The question was specifically about QListView and QFileSystemModel, not QListWidget. Your Answer doesn't work with a model/view system.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried connecting the QListView singal:

```
void clicked ( const QModelIndex & index )
```

to a slot and reading the data from the

```
QModelIndex::data
```

It will provide the index, check if its the first one, if it is, set it.